# problems with php array_filter and variables

Tags: php

I am trying to replace a date in my (working) array filter

```
$launch = date('Y-m-d H', $dtko['timestamp']).':00';
$day_3 = array_filter($check_day_3, function($obj){return $obj['time'] == '2017-02-25 15:00';});
```

with a variable ($launch):

```
$day_3 = array_filter($check_day_3, function($obj){return $obj['time'] == $launch;});
```

I don't get any error messages, but it doesn't work.
`echo $launch` shows exactly `2017-02-25 15:00`.

Ideas would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Does the code fail with an error or it does not match? Can you post how you're creating $launch variable pleas? Maby $launch does not contain '2017-02-25 15:00' string maby it's something else like a date object.

Comment: `echo $launch` shows exactly `2017-02-25 15:00`

Comment: You're assigning to `$day_3`, but want `$launch` to somehow change?

Comment: No, I want to have the date inside the $day_3 to be call from the variable `$launch` and not by `2017-02-25 15:00`

Answer (score 0):

$launch needs to be passed into the anonymous function. Its a scoping error.
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

```
// Inherit $message
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but didn't work. I don't get any error messages, `var_dump` shows me `string(16) "2017-02-25 15:00"`

Comment: Thats is it working correctly. $message is a type string that is 16 characters long. Add the `use ($yourVarHere)` to your anonymous function declaration and then you can use the var inside the function.

Comment: `$example = function () use ($launch); $day_3 = array_filter($check_day_3, function($obj){return $obj['time'] == $example;});` like that?

Comment: Almost :). This should do the trick: `$day_3 = array_filter($check_day_3,  function () use ($launch) {return $obj['time'] == $launch;});`
The `use $varName` is the command that passes a variable from outside the function to the inside, so it can be interacted with.

Comment: `$day_3 = array_filter($check_day_3, function () use ($launch) {return $obj['time'] == $launch;});` does not work :(

Comment: What does `function () use ($launch) {echo  $launch;}` return?

Comment: this breaks the page, blank page.

Comment: Please update the question with the entire logic block, all variables defined, and your current code.